# Django - multiple users with unique data

Tags: django

I'm building a SaaS that is something like a property maintenance application. A property maintenance company would use my application to manage multiple buildings and a whole bunch of tenants. So we have buildings and tenants all managed by one management company. However, a management company might have multiple staff (users) who are all managing these buildings/tenants.

Since this is a SaaS, I want to have a whole bunch of management companies all use my application to manage their own set of buildings/tenants. Thus, each management company needs to only be able to see their data and have no way to access another management company's data.

I have no idea how I might accomplish this in Django, though I have an idea:

Perhaps have a model called something like `ManagementCompany` and all buildings and tenants have a `ForeignKey` field which points to that `ManagementCompany` model. The staff of that management company would be connected to the `ManagementCompany` record via `ForeignKey`. In this way, the users can only see buildings/tenants whose `ManagementCompany` matches the users's.

Would that be a reasonable approach, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of subdomains?

> Custom subdomains are a great way to provide customization for customers of SaaS products and to differentiate content without resorting to long URL paths.

So when a company registers, you either take the company name call to_lower() method, or prompt them to choose the one they like, just like Slack does, or Jira. I suggest you read this article [Using Subdomains in Django Applications](https://wellfire.co/learn/multi-tennancy-in-django-using-subdomains/)

Comment: That's an interesting article, but doesn't it still open up the possibility of someone manually accessing someone else's data? For example, if the user has a subdomain of `user1.domain.com` and they just manually enter `user2.domain.com` won't the resulting data simply be that of `user2`? In their example, it would include the `Account` of `user2`? I mean, the idea of using subdomains is a great idea, but I feel like a bit more security would need to be built in, or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Well, that's where you need to implement authentications and authorizations. Also i didn't mean to create subdomains for each user, just for companies, and users have M2M relationships with companies (since you can work in both). So say a user has been authenticated in company1.domain.com, now if he creates a Building objects for example, the Building will have 2 fields, creator=user, company=company. Now if you want to show all the company1 buildings you would have a simple queryset of Building.objects.filter(company=company)

Comment: Yeah, a subdomain for each company with multiple users 'attached' to a company. This seems like a really interesting approach. I might go this route

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to store data in you SaaS application - single db for all instances or multiple db (each instance have separate database). Multiple db approach is pain when you want add new features, migrations etc. Single db is easier to manage but you need to add bunch of `ForeignKey` for each model.

For single db you will need:

1. Middleware that will detect SaaS instance (by subdomain, domain, port, custom url etc.).
2. Database router that will return database name for read/write depending on SaaS instance.

That's all. Django will read/write to separate databases.

For multiple db you will need:

1. Middleware that will detect SaaS instance (by subdomain, domain, port, custom url etc.).

Because you probably don't want to add `ForeignKey` to each model manually and filter it manually:

2. Abstract model with `ForeignKey` and custom save method to auto set that `ForeignKey`.
3. Custom model manager with custom `get_queryset` method that will filter all ORM queries with current SaaS instance. This manager should overide `create` method to auto set `ForeignKey` for queries like this: `Foo.objects.create(**data)`

Each model that will be fitlered for SaaS instance should inherit from that abstract model and you will need to set this model manager to that custom model manager.

That's all. Django will filter you ORM queries for current SaaS instance.

Example middleware (uses Domain model to check if domain exists, if not you will get HTTP404):

```
try:
    from threading import local
except ImportError:
    from django.utils._threading_local import local

_thread_locals = local()

def get_current_saas_instance():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'current_instance', None)

class SaaSSubdomainMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _thread_locals.current_instance = None
        host = request.get_host()

        try:
            domain = Domain.objects.get(name=host)
            _thread_locals.current_instance = domain.company
        except:
            logger.error('Error when checking SaaS domain', exc_info=True)
            raise Http404
```

Example abstract model:

```
class SaaSModelAbstract(Model):
    SAAS_FIELD_NAME = 'company'
    company = ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from .middleware import get_current_saas_instance
        self.company = get_current_saas_instance()
        super(SaaSModelAbstract, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Example model manager:

```
class CurrentSaaSInstanceManager(models.Manager):
    def get_current_saas_instance(self):
        from .middleware import get_current_saas_instance
        return get_current_saas_instance()

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_instance = self.get_current_saas_instance()

        if current_instance is not None:
            return super(CurrentSaaSInstanceManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
                **{self.model.SAAS_FIELD_NAME: current_instance})

        return super(CurrentSaaSInstanceManager, self).get_queryset()

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        current_instance = self.get_current_saas_instance()

        if current_instance is not None:
            kwargs[self.model.SAAS_FIELD_NAME] = current_instance

        instance = self.model(**kwargs)
        self._for_write = True
        instance.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
        return instance
```

Example models:

```
class FooModel(SaaSModelAbstract):
    # model fields, methods 

    objects = CurrentSaaSInstanceManager()

class BarModel(models.Model):
    # model fields, methods
    pass
```

Example queries:

```
FooModel.objects.all() # will return query with all objects for current SaaS instance
BarModel.objects.all() # will return all objects withoout SaaS filtering

# Create objects for SaaS instance:
FooModel.objects.create(**data)
# or:
foo = FooModel()
foo.save()
```

In both cases (single/multiple db) django admin will be working properly.

I'm not posted db router because implementation is trivial and all you need can be found in django docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas)

**Edit:**

Given that you mentioned in the comment to my original answer that the database being used is MySQL, django-tenant-schemas is useless in your case. How about using multiple databases with database routers, that ways there can be separate databases for every company and using database routers you can route request for your databases through it.

It might be overwork but you probably can figure out a slick way to do it.

Comment: Interesting app, but I'm using MySQL. The concept is intriguing.

Comment: @Garfonzo edited my answer after understanding you use, MySQL. Probably the edited answer may suit your requirements.

Comment: @Garfonzo With mutiple db and db router a user belonging to one company(which essentially will have one db instance of its own) wont be able to access other company's data

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I think that multiple databases would get tedious really quick with any updates and migrations.